# Mobile client authentification to API

Tags: api, authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0, authorization

I wonder what is right way to authentificate my mobile client to my backend REST API.
I have REST API backend with oauth2 functionality.
There is my web client which used oauth2 password grant flow.
User enters username and password on web client login page and then client sends post request to the backend along with client id and client secret. It is server to server communication so I can safely store client secret.
Now I have android mobile app. According to some recommedations it is not safe to store client secret in mobile app as it can be disassembled.
What oauth2 flow should I use for my mobile client?
Authorization code grant and password grant could not be used as I can not safely store client secret.
Implicit grant flow does not authenticate the identity of the application

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 [recommends](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9) mobile applications to either use the implicit grant or the code authorization grant. When using the code authorization grant, you should do so without authenticating the client by sending client id and secret (as you cannot keep secrets securely in the mobile client).

The implicit grant will not return a refresh token.